# Element not found exception thrown when try to locate to element in the new tab using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

**Scenario:**
The user clicks on a link/button. The new tab opens and is user redirected to the new tab..

**Problem:**
Now I want to perform some action on that new tab using selenium webdriver java. When I try to perform any action it displays me an `Exception` of `Element Not Found`.
I have tried **Switch_To_Tab** its not working.

Comment: Please paste your complete code

Comment: Here TestBase is my base file   
 public static void Click_Popular_Hotels_VR() throws Exception{

        TestBase.Click(POPULAR_HOTELS_OR_VR);

        TestBase.Sleep(3);

        TestBase.Switch_To_Tab(1);

        TestBase.Verify_Element(Page_ListingDetails.SHOW_ALL_PHOTOS_BUTTON);
    }

Comment: There is the possibility that element will be present inside a frame. Once the tab gets switched, read the title and check whether it matches or not. if it matches then look for iframe tag in the DOM, there is the possibility that desired element will be present inside a frame. Last thing that you can check is add expected conditions and wait until the visibility of an element and then perform the required operation on the web element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with this scenario a lot. I generally use windowHandles to switch focus to new tabs.

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("")).click();   //action to cause new tab to open
    //explicitWait will likely be needed here
    String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
           for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
             if(!winHandle.equals(winHandleBefore)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
```

At this point selenium should be focused on the new tab. You can complete whatever actions you want on this new tab. If you want to return to the previous tab you can use

```
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```